# Arch Linux sudo: command not found

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, root, sudo, archlinux

I recently installed Arch Linux on my Raspberry Pi and, after logging in as root and creating myself a user account I tried to use the sudo command.  This was the result:

```
[phillipus@alarmpi home]$ sudo mkdir Public
bash: sudo: command not found
```

After searching for the problem, I logged in as `root` and executed `pacman -S sudo`.  This was followed by a long output and a confirmation of installation.  Following this, I retried to use `sudo` both as `root` and as my user, both times getting the same response.  Following another solution to the problem, I tried to add myself to `/etc/sudoers`, only to find out that it didn't exist.

I am not very experienced with Linux, so could you please try to explain your responses fully?

Comment: Hi Phillipus, this is a better question for http://unix.stackexchange.com/. I think the moderators can move it over for you, but I'm not sure. Alternatively, the Arch linux IRC chat channel https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IRC_channel) would probably be able to help as well, a bit more promptly. They'd be better able to answer any follow up questions as well.

Answer (score 18):

First, you need to install the `sudo` package to use `sudo`:

```
pacman -S sudo
```

After that, you need to edit the `sudoers` file and add your username to it.

Comment: I would suggest to use `visudo` then , uncomment the group wheel line `%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL` . finally add the user to the wheel group `usermod -aG wheel your_user`

Comment: In my case it was recognizing sudo but the password no! by installing it with pacman it worked thank you so much. btw I had to type sudo, log-in and then install it; running sudo command for me was not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can add yor user to the wheel group using `usermod -G wheel yourusername` and uncomment the `%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL`line in the sudoers file. For more information, have a look at [Sudo - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sudo)